# Separating user resources - Windows Server 2008 (Terminal Server)

Tags: windows-server-2008

At the moment I am running a Windows Terminal Server 2008 for around 10 clients that use the server to run programs and access data.

Is there anyway to separate the resources of each user so that they do not impact each other in terms of resources.

- User 1: Opens program
- User 2: Notices slow down

I have looked into using [Windows System Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx) but do not know if it provides what I need and if there are any other 3rd party tools that also provide this functionality.

Any answer is appreciated.

Server Specs:

HP ProLiant ML110 G7

- Processor: Intel® Xeon® E3-1220 (4 core, 3.1 GHz, 8MB, 80W, 1333/t)
- RAM: 12GB DDR3 ECC
- 1TB HDD

Comment: What are the server's specs? It sounds like resource issues.

Comment: Specs are 
*Xeon E31220 
*12 GB RAM
*1TB HDD

I'm well aware of the resources required to run a terminal server. I just need to separate the resources.

Comment: Is that a single 1tb disk or an array?

Comment: Single, defiantly not a RAID0 :)

Comment: Fire up perfmon and find your bottlenecks.  I would guess your issue is running 10 users a single 1TB drive.  Resource management may help a bit, but if your system is truly overloaded, then you need more hardware.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache I understand the need to upgrade hardware if I cannot solve the bottlenecks

Comment: Have you checked this?
http://serverfault.com/questions/332622/find-out-the-bottleneck-for-windows-remote-desktop-server-terminal-server

Answer (score 2):

Windows System Resource Manager is exactly what you want. From the [technet page you linked to](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx):

> Manage system resources (processor and memory) with preconfigured
>   policies, or create custom policies that **allocate resources** per
>   process, per user, **per Remote Desktop Services session**, or per
>   Internet Information Services (IIS) application pool.

Setting up these policies requires a bit of finesse and a fine touch though, it's not something you just install and forget about. I suggest you [continue reading through the Technet articles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755056) and set up a staging environment to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for a valuable answer! I'm going to setup a test environment and see what needs to be configured in order to make Windows System Resource Manager do what I want.